# Using generics in Comparable

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement generics in Java using `Comparable<T>` interface.

```
public static <T> T[] sort(T[] a) {
    //need to compare 2 elements of a
}
```

Let's say, I want to override the `compareTo` method for the above type `T` in the `Comparable` interface. I.e. I need to compare two elements of my type `T`, how will I do it? I don't know what my `T` type will be.

Comment: Your title is rather ... generic.  Please make it more specific to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set a type constraint on your method.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T[] sort (T[] a)
{
         //need to compare 2 elements of a
}
```

This forces the type `T` to have the `compareTo(T other)` method.  This means you can do the following in your method:

```
if (a[i].compareTo(a[j]) > 0) }

}
```

Comment: @user, to be honest, I don't remember why you need the extra `? super T`.  The method will work in most cases if you just use `Comparable<T>`.

Comment: `<? super T>` stands for an unknown type that is a super-type of `T`, or possibly `T` itself.  Likewise `<? extends T>` is an unknown sub-type of T, or again possibly T itself.

Comment: The `? super T` allows you to have: `class Person implements Comparable<Person>; class Student extends Person;` and do `sort(new Student[] {});`

Comment: @jjnguy: `? super T` also handles old classes that just implement raw `Comparable` correctly. If you make it `T extends Comparable<T>`, the method will be unusable with an array of such a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<T extends Comparable<T>>` and then `compareTo`

Answer (score 0):

Old question but...

As jjnguy responded, you need to use:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T[] sort(T[] a) {
  ...
}
```

Consider the following:

```
public class A implements Comparable<A> {}
public class B extends A {}
```

The class `B` implicitly implements `Comparable<A>`, not `Comparable<B>`, hence your sort method could not be used on an array of `B`'s if used `Comparable<T>` instead of `Comparable<? super T>`.  To be more explicit:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] brokenSort(T[] a) {
   ...
}
```

would work just fine in the following case:

```
A[] data = new A[3];
...
data = brokenSort(A);
```

because in this case the type parameter `T` would be bound to `A`.  The following would produce a compiler error:

```
B[] data = new B[3];
...
data = brokenSort(B);
```

because `T` cannot be bound to `B` since `B` does not implement `Comparable<B>`.